Gas estimation error when trying to send ERC 20 to multiple addresses
I was trying to programmatically send ERC 20 tokens from one wallet to multiple other wallets
Here is the code from Disperse App that I referenced to:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}


contract Disperse {

    function disperseToken(IERC20 token, address[] calldata recipients, uint256[] calldata values) external {
        uint256 total = 0;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
            total += values[i];
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), total));
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
            require(token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]));
    }

    function disperseTokenSimple(IERC20 token, address[] calldata recipients, uint256[] calldata values) external {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
            require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, recipients[i], values[i]));
    }

    function disperseTokenSameAmount(IERC20 token, address[] calldata recipients, uint256 value) external{
        uint256 total = value * recipients.length;
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), total));
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++)
            require(token.transfer(recipients[i], value));
    }
}

I have tried two things:

Sent the token directly to the contract and called disperseToken, it does not work

Not sending any tokens to the contract, and directly called disperseToken


(I am sure that I have enough amount of tokens and my input parameters are all correct!)
But none of them work!
So my questions are:

Do I have to send the token directly to the contract so that it will work?
How do I make it so that the contract will directly spend my token (through the approval process), and send it to wallets?
How do I fix it and implement it into ethers js?

Thank you!

Call approve at the token contract, from the token holders address, passing your disperse contract as the spender and the number you want to transfer as the amount.


No. It wants the balance from wallet of the msg.sender.

        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), total));

transferFrom will spend an allowance, granted in a previouse transaction.

Call approve at the token contract, from the token holders address, passing your disperse contract as the spender and the number total as the amount.

I don't use js to script you the example but you want to call disperseToken, with



your tokens address.
1 array that contains the addresses you want to disperse to.
1 array that contains the values you want to disperse to each.

A simple implementation would use a web3 library to create a contract instance of the disperse contract using its address and abi. 
Then using that instance to build the transaction and calldata, signing using the key of the holder, and then sending the transaction.

You probably need to approve the Disperse contract to spend your tokens for the amount that you want, in the token contract.
also you should revert with errors so debugging becomes easier, or at least pass the error string to the require function:
require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), total), "couldn't transfer tokens from sender wallet to contract");

